# Python: Replace an escaped quote with another character

Tags: python, json, regex, parsing, double-quotes

I have a JSON containing HTML, and I need to make it parsable. Pandas can't import this kind of JSON.

```
text = """[{
   "article_id": 3540349,
   "site_id": 1563,
   "domain": "https:\/\/ear.rt.hm",
   "code": "wta-jurmala-benara-u-ctrtl",
   "uri": "https:\/\/ar.rl.hq\/spormala-berera-u-cetinalu\/",
   "content_type": {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "article"
   },
   "article_type": {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "article"
   },
   "created": "2019-07-25 23:58:20",
   "modified": "2019-07-25 23:59:19",
   "publish_date": "2019-07-25 23:58:00",
   "active": true,
   "author": "<a href=\"https:\/\/spt02.com\" target=\"_blank\">I 
Kapri<\/a>"
}]"""

text = text.replace('\"', "'")
```

The result is (nevermind the text difference):

```
'author': '<a href='https:\/\/spo.hq' target='_blank'>Iv<\/a>'
```

When I try to replace '\"' I then get:

```
"author": "<a href="https:\/\/spr.hq" target="_blank">Ilari<\/a>"
```

Which again wasn't what I wanted.

Does anyone know how to properly escape \" to ' ?

Comment: `\"` and `"` inside a `"""` regular string literal are the same `"` chars, `print( """ " \" """)` => `" "`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/QZXdO8). `'\"'` = `'"'`, so all you do with `.replace('\"', "'")` is replace each `"` with `'`

Comment: @Ivan Ivković: Whats the error and how do you load the data into Pandas ? According to jsonlint.com your JSON data is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you escaped these \ characters when you shouldn't. Use the raw string by adding an **r** ahead of """

```
import json
text = r"""[{
   "article_id": 35449,
   "site_id": 153,
   "domain": "https:\/\/ezt.hq",
   "code": "wta-jurrda-pe-cetlu",
   "uri": "https:\/\/ezl.hr\/s0349\/wla-balu\/",
   "content_type": {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "article"
   },
   "article_type": {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "article"
   },
   "created": "2019-07-25 23:58:20",
   "modified": "2019-07-25 23:59:19",
   "publish_date": "2019-07-25 23:58:00",
   "active": true,
   "author": "<a href=\"https:\/\/spr2.hr\" target=\"_blank\">Iari<\/a>"
}]"""
obj = json.loads(text)
```

If you read text from a txt file, replace `text = r"""..."""` with `text = open(file_name).read()`

Comment: Yea, the bigger problem was testing with the string inside the code than parsing the original stuff in the first place. Tried parsing the JSON directly. Thanks!